# cannot run sample apps, missing libudev.so.0?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, chromium

I'm just starting out with dart.  I have installed the editor on ubuntu linux.  when I try and run any of the sample files I get this error box:

> Could not launch browser - process terminated while trying to connect.
>   Try closing and running Dartium instances.:
>
> Dartium stdout: /home/xxx/Apps/dart/chromium/chrome:error while
>   loading share libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory

I have followed the step by step instructions at code.google.com for installation and run all of the pertinent scripts.  I have also installed chromium via apt-get and pointed to it in the tools menu.  Still get the message.

Where do I get this missing file?  or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I found [here](http://kiawin.com/blog/2012/11/cannot-open-shared-object-libudev-so-0.html) the answer.

Basically, first I had to install the libudev-dev package and after that I created a link to point to libudev:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
```

Be happy!

Comment: My terminal says that this path does not exist!!

Comment: The path would depend on the system, on Ubuntu 18.04 it is located at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. So it would be 
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0

Answer (score 0):

The official solution [PreparingYourMachine](https://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/PreparingYourMachine) on dart wiki is somewhat complicated. If you have already installed Chrome with Google's deb installer (I installed Chrome with "google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb" which is downloaded from [Chrome website](https://www.google.com/chrome/)), there is a simple way to resolve this problem:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/google/chrome/libudev.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
```

Works on Linux Mint 17 x86_64.

PS: I met a "404 not found" error when install libudev-dev with aptitude.